# Is the Kineticist's Aether Utility Talent: Dual Telekinetic Control a multiple attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, attack-roll, kineticist

Is the Kineticist's Aether Utility Talent: Dual Telekinetic Control a multiple attack?

> [**Dual Telekinetic Control**](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/aether-utility-talents#toc11)
>
> **Element(s):** aether; **Level:** 1; **Type:** utility (Su); **Burn** —
>
> **Prerequisite(s):** telekinetic blast
>
> You can use your telekinetic blast with two objects simultaneously. This has no effect on the blast’s damage, and their combined weight cannot exceed the normal weight limit for telekinetic blast. The objects must remain within the same space as one another for the duration of the blast, and if thrown, must be thrown at the same target.

And

> [Telekinetic Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/kineticist-elements/)
>
> **Element(s):** aether; **Type:** simple blast (Sp); **Level:** —; **Burn** 0
> **Blast Type:** physical; **Damage:** bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing
>
> You throw a nearby unattended object at a single foe as a ranged attack. The object must weigh no more than 5 pounds per kineticist level you possess. If the attack hits, the target and the thrown object each take the blast’s damage. Since the object is enfolded in strands of aether, even if you use this power on a magic weapon or other unusual object, the attack doesn’t use any of the magic weapon’s bonuses or effects; it simply deals your blast damage. Alternatively, you can loosen the strands of aether in order to deal damage to both the object and the target as though you had thrown the object yourself (instead of dealing your normal blast damage).
>
> You substitute your Constitution modifier for your Strength modifier if throwing the object would have added your Strength modifier on the damage roll, and you don’t take the –4 penalty on the attack roll for throwing an object that wasn’t designed to be thrown. In this case, the object’s special effects apply (including effects from its materials), and if the object is a weapon, you must be proficient with it and able to wield it with one hand; otherwise, the item deals damage as a one-handed improvised weapon for a creature of your size.

If so....

1. Does that mean one or separate attack roll for both projectiles?
2. Does both projectiles deal damage to the target or the first attack that hits?

Comment: I'm really curious: Is the given answer incomplete? Unclear? What can I do to it so that it answers the question satisfactorily?

Answer (score 1):

Because these are both complicated abilities *and* because one ability requires the reader to make multiple exceptions to the other ability, I just went ahead and rewrote *both* abilities as one combined ability. Presented below is that rewrite, and this is how I'd implement the spell-like ability [**telekinetic blast**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/kineticist-elements/#Telekinetic_Blast) with the new exceptions from the supernatural ability [**dual telekinetic control**](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/aether-utility-talents#toc11) folded in:

> **You throw two nearby unattended objects at a single foe as a ranged attack.** The objects' combined weight must be no more than 5 pounds per kineticist level you possess. **If the attack hits, the target and the thrown objects each take the blast’s damage.** Since the objects are enfolded in strands of aether, even if you use this power on magic weapons or other unusual objects, the attack doesn’t use any of the magic weapons’ bonuses or effects; it simply deals your blast damage.
>
> **Alternatively, you can** loosen the strands of aether in order to **deal damage to both the pair of objects and the target as though you had thrown the objects yourself (instead of dealing your normal blast damage)**. You substitute your Constitution modifier for your Strength modifier if throwing the objects would have added your Strength modifier on the damage roll, and you don’t take the –4 penalty on the attack roll for throwing either object if it wasn’t designed to be thrown. In this case, each object’s special effects apply (including effects from its materials), and if the objects are weapons, you must be proficient with them and able to wield each of them with one hand; otherwise, the items deal damage as one-handed improvised weapons for a creature of your size.

(In addition to incorporating into the ability telekinetic blast the exceptions made by the ability dual telekinetic control, I also take responsibility for the emphasis and minor paragraph reorganization.) I think this modified description that combines the two abilities addresses the questions, but just to be extra clear, here are specific answers:

- ***Does a kineticist that uses the ability dual kinetic attack make one attack roll or two?***

  The kineticist makes one attack roll.
- ***If the attack roll is successful, does each object deal damage?***

  If the attack roll is successful, the kineticist may opt to deal damage with *both* objects (as per the second paragraph, above). If he wanted to, instead of dealing the damage with *both* objects, the kineticist could deal *only* his blast damage; in that case, the kineticist deals his blast damage only once.